# Lucene - Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock on fast requests

Tags: lucene, httpmodule

i have an `httpmodule` that logs every visit to the site into a lucene index.
the site is hosted on godaddy and even due i have almost nothing on the page i do the tests on (about 3kb including css), it works slow.

if i try to refresh a few times, after the second or third refresh i would get `Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock` error.

my question is, am i doing something wrong? or is this normal behavior?
is there any way to overcome this problem?

my code:

```
        //state the file location of the index
        string indexFileLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "Analytics");
        Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexFileLocation, false);

        //create an analyzer to process the text
        Lucene.Net.Analysis.Analyzer analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer();

        //create the index writer with the directory and analyzer defined.
        Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter indexWriter = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, false);

        //create a document, add in a single field
        Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
        doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.NO));
        doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("IP", request.UserHostAddress.ToString(), Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.NO));

        //write the document to the index
        indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);

        //optimize and close the writer
        //indexWriter.Optimize();
        indexWriter.Close();
```